# Extracting information

Tags: python

I want to extract `myinformation_1` and `myinformation_2` from the list below.

My code is not working yet.

Can you please help?

Thank you,HHC

```
import re
start = re.escape(">")
end   = re.escape("<")
stringlist =['<div class="ant-space-item"><a href="/holdings-of-1">myinformation_1</a></div>', 
    '<div class="ant-space-item"><a href="/holdings-of-2avbf">myinformation_2</a></div>']
for i in stringlist :
    result = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), i).group(1)
    print(result)
```

Comment: Checkout xmltree

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1):

Try with a more specific regex, e.g. `<a href="/holdings-of-[^"]+">([^<]*)` in this case:

```py
import re

stringlist =['<div class="ant-space-item"><a href="/holdings-of-1">myinformation_1</a></div>',
    '<div class="ant-space-item"><a href="/holdings-of-2adf">myinformation_2</a></div>']

for i in stringlist:
    result = re.search(r'<a href="/holdings-of-[^"]+">([^<]*)', i).group(1)
    print(result)
```

Output:

```
myinformation_1
myinformation_2
```

Or as suggested in the comments, you can use a more "generalized" expression that works for any `<a>` tag, such as a regex like `<a.*?>([^<]*)`.

Comment: Or, to be even more general, just `r'<a.*?>([^<]*)</a.*'`

Comment: Yep, a good point. I was trying to aim for specific, but that's a good generalization to use too.

Comment: This one is easier for newbee to read. (r'<a href="/holdings-of-\d+">([^<]*). What if the start is not end with number but <a href="/holdings-of-2adf">myinformation_1?

Comment: @Hary2 hmm, in that case you can use `\w` instead of `\d`, which will match either numbers or letters. I updated the solution above.

Comment: actually, I just realized there's an even better (likely also faster) solution. We can just match `[^"]` or any character other than a quote `"`, which terminates the href value.